# Intermittent "Cannot GET /" with node.js on Bluemix

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ibm-cloud

For some reason on all my Bluemix services, I intermittently get the error "Cannot GET /pathname" on my node.js express services. This is intermittent (it works about 1/3 of the time). There is no error or logging shown in the application when this happens (however that response is coming from express I assume).

Any ideas? I have no idea how to progress here. The server has ample resources (memory + CPU).

Comment: Can you share some of the code you have with us?

Comment: You need to provide more details so someone can help you. First thing I would do is to make sure the application runs fine in your local environment. Second try checking the logs with `cf logs appname --recent` for errors. Third you can run `cf events appname` to see if your app is constantly crashing and Bluemix is automatically restarting it, if this is the case you would see sporadic errors when you are trying to access the app and it is restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen before when the user accidently has 2 different applications mapped to the same route/URL. The load balancer is hitting a different application on each time.

Try changing the route to something else and try to recreate the problem....myappname**2**.mybluemix.net

If that seems to fix it, log in to the UI and confirm that you do not have duplicate applications and that all applications have a unique route.

Comment: Thanks - this solved the problem for me. Somehow I had two applications deployed to the same route and therefore it was intermittently hitting the wrong app. I deleted the incorrect mapping and its working correctly now. Thanks!